# Forking a GitHub repo and dealing with .min files

Tags: github, fork, min.js

I fork this repo https://github.com/Esri/ago-assistant and cloned to my machine and "npm install" to get the dependencies.

But when I try to open the index.html in the console I get errors about files "missing". I say "missing" because the files are there but they don't have the ".min.js" file extension just ".js".

How do I fix this other than going to all the files manually changing the extension? Or what's a better apporach or best practice here? Thanks

Comment: Do you execute `npm run build` after restoring the packages?

Comment: I did it just now and yes that work thanks! Found in the "build" folder, if you want to submit as answer I'll make as correct

Comment: execute `npm run build:js` to regenerate the main.min.js bundle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **best** way to handle this would be to minify the files yourself using the process the project recommends. According to the `package.json` of the project, they're using **[`Babel`](https://babeljs.io/)** in combination with **[`uglify-js`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-js)**.

You **should** be able to resolve this by simply running `build:js` from the project folder, which will launch the build script for the project, including the minifcation component: `uglifyjs -c -o build/js/main.min.js`.

As an alternative, you should also be able to run the relevant task from Visual Studio's `Task Runner Explorer` (`View --> Other Windows --> Task Runner Explorer`). If the task does not show up, installing the **[NPM Task Manager Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.NPMTaskRunner)** should force it to.